# Recursively Draw a Box JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to draw a box inside of another the inner, and keep drawing them until the width is 2px

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/443wovkk/

JavaScript:

```
var innerBox = $('.box');
var innerBoxDimentions;
var boxHtml = innerBox.clone().removeClass('outter');

$(document).ready(function(){

    do {  
        innerBox = findInnerBox(innerBox);
        innerBoxDimentions = innerBox.width() / 2;


        boxHtml = boxHtml.width(innerBoxDimentions).height(innerBoxDimentions);
        innerBox.append(boxHtml);
    }
    while (innerBoxDimentions > 2);

    //var boxHtml = innerBox.clone().width(innerBoxDimentions/2).height(innerBoxDimentions/2);
    innerBox.append(boxHtml);

});


function findInnerBox(box){
    if(box.children('.box').length > 0){
        findInnerBox(box.children('.box'))
    } else{
       return box;
    }
}
```

Currently it only draws one box. It should keep drawing more boxes inside the inner most box until the last box is 2px wide.

How do I recursively draw a box inside the inner most box continuously until the last box drawn reaches 2px wide?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: Why did my question get down voted, i just want an answer, and now nobody will look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two critical problems with your code keeping it from working.

1) You are always updating the same "box" variable.  You need to create a different one each time.  I fixed this by adding a call to `clone()`.

2) The recursive function does not return a value after recursing.  Add a `return` here in `findInnerBox`.

The following code does what you want with those minor adjustments:

```js
var innerBox = $('.box');
var innerBoxDimentions;
var boxHtml = innerBox.clone().removeClass('outter');

$(document).ready(function(){

    do {  
        innerBox = findInnerBox(innerBox);
        innerBoxDimentions = innerBox.width() / 2;


        boxHtml = boxHtml.clone().width(innerBoxDimentions).height(innerBoxDimentions);
        innerBox.append(boxHtml);
    }
    while (innerBoxDimentions > 2);

    //var boxHtml = innerBox.clone().width(innerBoxDimentions/2).height(innerBoxDimentions/2);
    innerBox.append(boxHtml);

});


function findInnerBox(box){
    if(box.children('.box').length > 0){
        return findInnerBox(box.children('.box'))
    } else{
       return box;
    }
}
```

```css
/* CSS Styles for Recursive Box */

.box{ border:solid 1px #000; }
.outter { width: 500px; height:500px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box outter"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Opps, too late I guess.
Here is my version of the code

```
var size = 500;
while(size = size - 20){
    $('.box:last').append('<div class="'+size+' box"></div>');
    $('.'+size).css('height',size).css('width',size);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/443wovkk/2/